# numpy and cv2, no modules available after installation via pip on linux

Tags: python, linux, numpy, opencv, pip

I installed opencv and numpy using pip on debian 11.2 with python 3.9.
In visual studio the modules aren't available and terminal returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dominik/projects/object_detection/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

python console returns information about packages version.

```
pip show opencv-python
Name: opencv-python
Version: 4.5.5.64
Summary: Wrapper package for OpenCV python bindings.
Home-page: https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python
Author: None
Author-email: None
License: MIT
Location: /home/dominik/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: numpy, numpy, numpy
Required-by:
```

how to deal with it?

Comment: If you have multiple version/interpreter of Python installed this can be an issue. Can you check the directory is actually created in `/home/dominik/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages`? Then please check the paths in `sys.path`. By the way, you can certainly install the python module of OpenCV from the Debian repository (which will be updated automatically with the other packages on your machine).

Comment: @JérômeRichard in .local/lib/python3.9/site-packages$ I have the next directories: 
cv2, numpy-1.22.3.dist-info, opencv_python-4.5.5.64.dist-info, numpy, numpy.libs,             opencv_python.libs. chow tu check sys.path? I would like to keep separate environments for different projects, so I don't want to add opencv to the debian repository.

Comment: Ok so it looks like the directory of OpenCV is installed as expected but this does not means that the CPython launched use this one which is the purpose of checking `sys.path`. Can you just print the content of `sys.path` in the question? (you need to `import sys` first)

Comment: @JérômeRichard sys.patch returns following list: ['', '/usr/lib/python39.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.9', '/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/home/dominik/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

Comment: Thank you, this is weird as the path is present so it should be found. Is there a proper cv2.so in `/home/dominik/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages` ? Btw, do you use Conda? (there are some well-known issue with it).

Comment: @JérômeRichard ` /home/dominik/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2 ` contains the following files and directories: ` config-3.py, data, LICENSE-3RD-PARTY.txt, load_config_py,3.py, __pycache__, version.py, config.py, gapi, LICENSE.txt, mat_wrapper, qt, cv2.abi3.so, __init__.py, load_config_py2.py, misc, utils` I don't use anaconda but I fink about it if I don't fix this issue.

Comment: I have a similar directory on my Linux (and also a directory called `opencv_python.libs`). When you do an import, CPython typically search for the "site-packages" directory in the searched path to find a directory with the name of the imported module. It then search for a file named `__init__.py` which is present. If you set the working directory to `/home/dominik/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages` and type `import cv2` it should be able to load the local one. You may need to add `.` to the `PATH` environment variable but CPython should already search in the current directory.